# Conditional rendering of HTML in Golang layout.tpl by session variable

Tags: html, go

I use Gorilla sessions (via negroni-sessions) to store my **user** sessions in cookies. I also use `github.com/unrolled/render` for my HTML template rendering:

**main.go:**

```
    package main

    import (
        ...
        "github.com/codegangsta/negroni"
        "github.com/goincremental/negroni-sessions"
        "github.com/goincremental/negroni-sessions/cookiestore"
        "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
        "github.com/unrolled/render"
        ...
    )

    func init() {
        ...
        ren = render.New(render.Options{
            Directory:     "templates",
            Layout:        "layout",
            Extensions:    []string{".html"},
            Funcs:         []template.FuncMap{TemplateHelpers}, 
            IsDevelopment: false,
        })
        ...
    }

    func main() {
        ...
        router := httprouter.New()
        router.GET("/", HomeHandler)

        // Add session store
        store := cookiestore.New([]byte("my password"))
        store.Options(sessions.Options{
            //MaxAge: 1200,
            Domain: "",
            Path:   "/",
        })

        n := negroni.New(
            negroni.NewRecovery(),
            sessions.Sessions("cssession", store),
            negroni.NewStatic(http.Dir("../static")), 
        )

        n.UseHandler(router)
        n.Run(":9000")

    }
```

As you can see above, I use a **layout.html** master HTML template which is included when any page renders, like my home page:

```
    package main

    import (
        "html/template"
        "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    )

    func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {

        var model = struct {
            CatalogPicks   []PromotionalModelList
            ClearanceItems []Model
        }{
            CatalogPicks:   GetCatalogPicks(),
            ClearanceItems: GetClearanceItems(),
        }

        ren.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "home", model)
    }
```

In my **layout.html** master HTML template, I want to render an admin menu but only if the current user is an admin:

**layout.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{{ template "title" . }}</title>
        ...
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <!--Main Menu-->
      <nav class="menu">
         <ul class="catalog">
             <li class="has-submenu">
                {{ RenderMenuCategories }}
             </li>
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Blog</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Company</a></li>

             {{ RenderAdminMenu }}

         </ul>
      </nav>
```

...

My issue is that the above template helper function `RenderAdminMenu()` doesn't have access to the HTTP Request object and therefore cannot access the **User** session object to determine if the user is admin.

I can pass the User object into the template context via the Home page handler, and use an `if` statement RenderAdminMenu() function, like this

```
{{ if .User.IsAdmin }}
   {{ RenderAdminMenu }}
{{ end }}
```

...but since I am using a master template, I would have to do that from every web page on the site. Is there a more efficient way?

I was thinking perhaps there might be a way to access some kind of global `Context` object from within `RenderAdminMenu()` (or layout.html) which contains the `Request` details (like you can in ASP.NET)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you need to do to tie this together. I'm not going to show a complete example as it would be both fairly lengthy and may not match your code (which you haven't posted). It will contain the basic building blocks though: if you get stuck, come back with a direct question and a code snippet and you'll get a more direct answer :)

1. Write some middleware or logic in a [login] handler that saves the user data in the session when a user logs in. A userID, email and admin boolean value would be sufficient. e.g.

   ```
   // In your login handler, once you've retrieved the user &
   // matched their password hash (scrypt, of course!) from the DB.
   session.Values["user"] = &youruserobject
   err := session.Save(r, w)
   if err != nil {
       // Throw a HTTP 500
   }
   ```

Note: remember that you need to `gob.Register(&youruserobject{})` as per the [gorilla/sessions docs](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions#overview) if you want to store your own types.

2. Write a helper to type-assert your type when you pull it out of the session, e.g.

   ```
   var ErrInvalidUser= errors.New("invalid user stored in session")

   func GetUser(session *sessions.Session) (*User, error) {
       // You can make the map key a constant to avoid typos/errors
       user, ok := session.Values["user"].(*User)
       if !ok || user == nil {
           return nil, ErrInvalidUser
       }
       return user, nil
   }


   // Use it like this in a handler that serves user content
   session, err := store.Get("yoursessionname", r)
   if err != nil {
       // Throw a HTTP 500
   }

   user, err := GetUser(session)
      if err != nil {
       // Re-direct back to the login page or
       // show a HTTP 403 Forbidden, etc.
   }
   ```
3. Write something to check if the returned user is an admin:

   ```
   func IsAdmin(user *User) bool {
           if user.Admin == true && user.ID != "" && user.Email != "" {
                   return true
           }

           return false
   }
   ```
4. Pass that to the template:

   ```
    err := template.Execute(w, "sometemplate.html", map[string]interface{}{
           "admin": IsAdmin(user),
           "someotherdata": someStructWithData,
       }

    // In your template...
    {{ if .admin }}{{ template "admin_menu" }}{{ end }}
   ```

Also make sure you're setting an authentication key for your session cookies (read the gorilla docs), preferably an encryption key, and that you're serving your site over HTTPS with the Secure: true flag set as well.

Keep in mind that the above method is also simplified: if you de-flag a user as admin in your DB, the application will continue to detect them as an administrator for as long as their session lasts. By default this can be 7 days, so if you're in a risky environment where admin churn is a real problem, it may pay to have really short sessions *OR* hit the DB inside the `IsAdmin` function just to be safe. If it's a personal blog and it's just you, not so much.

---

**Added**: If you want to pass the User object *directly* to the template, you can do that too. Note that it's more performant to do it in your handler/middleware than it is in the template logic. You also get the flexibility of more error handling, and the option of "bailing out" earlier - i.e. if the session contains nothing, you can fire up a HTTP 500 error rather than rendering half a template or having to put lots of logic in your template to handle `nil` data.

You still need to store your `User` object (or equivalent) in the session, and retrieve it from `session.Values` before you can pass it to the template.

```
 func GetUser(r *http.Request) *User {
        session, err := store.Get("yoursessionname", r)
        if err != nil {
            // Throw a HTTP 500
        }
        if user, ok := session.Values["user"].(*User); ok {
            return user
        }

        return nil
 }

 // In the handler itself
 err := template.Execute(w, "sometemplate.html", map[string]interface{}{
        "user": GetUser(r),
        "someotherdata": someStructWithData,
        }


 // In your template...
 {{ if .User.admin }}{{ template "admin_menu" }}{{ end }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer but unfortunately it doesn't resolve my issue. I've already covered all the steps you mention. What I need is a way to access the HTTP Request object from a template helper (which is not a handler) so that I can access the user's session object.

Comment: You could write a template helper similar to my `IsAdmin` function and have it return a `User` object straight to the template - i.e. `GetUser(r *http.Request) User` - with the function pulling the User object out of the session (if it exists). This is very similar to what I've shown above, but puts more work into the template (not ideal; limited error checking).

If I'm still misinterpreting your question, show your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot access the `Request` context from a template or a template helper function afterall (so I accepted the answer above). My solution was to create a `Page` struct that I pass as the context for every template. It contains the `Content` as a generic interface, the `User` object, as well as other useful parameters:

```
//Page holds the model to be rendered for every HTTP handler.
type Page struct {
     MetaTitle     string
     User          User
     HeaderStyles  string
     HeaderScripts string
     FooterScripts string
     Content       interface{}
 }

 func (pg *Page) Init(r *http.Request) {

    if pg.MetaTitle == "" {
        pg.MetaTitle = "This is the default <title> content for the page!"
    }

    user, _ := GetUserFromSession(r)
    pg.User = *user

    if user.IsAdmin() {
        pg.HeaderStyles += `<link href="/css/libs/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">`
        pg.FooterScripts += `<script src="/js/libs/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>`
    }

}
```

The Init method allows me to set defaults and use the Page struct more easily, by specifying only the `Content` for the page, if that's all I need:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {

    var model = struct {
        CatalogPicks   []PromotionalModelList
        ClearanceItems []Model
    }{
        CatalogPicks:   GetCatalogPicks(),
        ClearanceItems: GetClearanceItems(),
    }

    pg := &Page{Content: model}
    pg.Init(r)
    ren.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "home", pg)
}
```